# How to upload,save and display file with node and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new in nodejs and i am trying to make form with node and express that can upload save and display image or file.
i have the app.post information that works.

i was trying something but it did not work.
well i think i a missing something but i dont really know what i tried many answers but nothing worked for me.
Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advanced.

There is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var Busboy = require('busboy');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyparser());

app.get('/information', function(req,res) {
  var html = '<form action="/information" method="post">' +
           'Enter your name:' +
           '<input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="..." />' +
           '<br>' +
           '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
        '</form>';               
res.send(html);
});

app.post('/information', function(req, res){
  var userName = req.body.userName;
  var html = 'Hello: ' + userName + '.<br>' +
         '<a href="/information">Try again.</a>';
  res.send(html);
}); 

var frm = '<form action="/file" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-    data">' + '<br/>'+
        '<input type="file" name="uploadFile" />' + '<br/>' + 
        '<input type="submit" />' + '</form>';

app.get('/file',function(req,res){
    res.send(frm);
});

app.post('/file',function(req,res){

    fs.readFile(req.body.uploadFile.path , function (err, data) {
        var fileName = req.body.uploadFile.name;
        if(!fileName){
            console.log("There was an error")
            res.redirect("/file");
            res.send();
        } else {

          var newPath = "/uploads/" + fileName;

          /// write file to uploads folder
          fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {

            /// let's see it
            res.redirect("/uploads/" + fileName);
          });
        }
    });
});
/// Show files
app.get('/uploads/:file', function (req, res){
     file = req.params.file;
    var img = fs.readFileSync("/uploads/" + file);
    res.send(img, 'binary');
});app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3003);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong here:

- The `enctype` value in your form has spaces in the middle (`multipart/form-    data`)
- The `busboy` middleware is not being used at all, only the `body-parser` middleware is being used, which does not support `multipart/form-data`.
- `busboy` itself does not populate `req.body`. If you want that kind of API, then you should probably look at [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), which is built on `busboy` but provides `req.body`.